# Why is JAX-RS/restEasyClient async not working as async

Tags: java, asynchronous, jax-rs, resteasy

may be I am not understanding the ASYNC part of this. 
I have a resteasy client ( only one client )

```
client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(maxConnections).connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).httpEngine(engine).build();
```

where maxConenctions is 10, the client is created on startup and does async calls on each request like this in a for loop :

```
ResteasyWebTarget resteasyWebTarget = client.target(restRequestFromGateway.getUrl());
        Future<Response>  response = resteasyWebTarget.
                          request().
                          headers(headers).
                          async().
                          get(restWSResponseCallback);

 if (response!= null){
                    response.isDone();
                }
```

I created ten requests and in a for loop send them through. on the WebService end I  put a debug point and just waited. So i got the first request and didnt let it go through.

I was expecting that as it was async the client will continue and will send multiple requests and wait for the response in the invocationCallback but it did not

the next request didnt come thorugh to the webservice till the response from the webservice was received.
Why didn't the requests go through one by one after the another from the client.

Comment: You should read the docs on `Future.get`

Comment: @Dummy thanks for the reply. From https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter13/async_invoker_client_api.html it says: "I suggest that you only use the Future.cancel() and Future.isDone() methods, though, as you may have concurrency issues with InvocationCallback" So I dont need to do get. restWSResponseCallback is an implementation of InvocationCallback.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/232f9f465f0e28a90903c3fddd3dbb0a). You can see how the requests are just fire-and-forget requests, using a CountDownLatch to determine when all of them are complete.

Comment: What type of verifications are you using to test for asynchrony? You can see in my tests in the link what I did. It checks out.

Comment: So what happened?

Comment: Sorry, I tested it and I was debugging it I think wrongly. It was working async and going through.